# migrating from calloc() to new

Tags: c++, c++98, construction

I came across a large pod struct, in which I wanted to add a `std::vector` member.

```
struct LargePodStruct {
    float x,y,z;
    int *arr;
    int sz;
    ...            // dozens of primitive types
    std::vector<int> the_new_vector;
};
```

In order to add a `vector` to this struct, I needed to replace all `calloc()` instantiations of this struct with `new`.

Also, I need to instantiate each existing member to zero.
However, adding a default constructor which instantiates every member to zero is a mundane task. It's also easy to forget to instantiate a new member in the future.

```
LargePodStruct::LargePodStruct()
    x(), y(), z(), arr(), sz(), ... // +dozens of instantiations
{}
```

1. Is there an easier way to instantiate the primitive members of this struct with less effort?
2. Is there a good & elegant way to zero-instantiate a union member as well?

.

```
struct LargePodStruct {
    float x,y,z;
    int *arr;
    int sz;
    ...            
    union { 
        int i;
        void *ptr;
     } u;
    std::vector<int> the_new_vector;
};
```

Comment: You may try `memset()`!

Comment: Consider adding a default member initializer to all of your members such as `int * arr = nullptr;` and `int sz = 0;` directly in the class definition.

Comment: Since C++11 you can directly initialise them on their declaration eg: `int sz = 0;`

Comment: Unrelated: Depending on the ownership of whatever `int *arr;` is pointing at, you may find yourself having to observe the [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It may be easier to `vector`-ize this sucker as well.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, if my struct also contained a nested `union` (say of ints & pointers), is there a way to zero-initialize the union as well, using this syntax?

Comment: @GrimFandango I'm not familiar with it, but it's described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization).

Comment: Is C++98 mandratory?

Comment: @kiner_shah, (+1) your proposal is the only alternative for c++98.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it is for me, but I am also curious how this case is currently handled.

Comment: Can you not replace the pair {arr,sz} with a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename V>
struct zdf{
    V value;
    zdf():value{}{};
    operator V&(){return value;};
    operator V()const{return value;};
    V operator()const{return value;};
    V& operator(){return value};
};

struct LargeModernValue{
    zdf<float> x,y,z;
    std::vector<int> arr;
    std::any u;/*std::variant<int,void*> u;*/
    //....
    std::vector<int> theNewVec;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You *could* continue to allocate a raw memory block using `calloc()`, and then use [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to construct the struct inside that memory block:

```
void *buffer = calloc(1, sizeof(LargePodStruct));
LargePodStruct *s = new(buffer) LargePodStruct;
```

However, you will not be able to use `delete` to free the struct, you must call its destructor directly and then `free()` the memory block:

```
s->~LargePodStruct();
free(buffer);
```

Comment: Why not ? Won't `delete` call `free()` anyway ?

Comment: @GrimFandango not guaranteed, no, just as `new` is not guaranteed to use `malloc()` internally. You must match allocators with their documented freers correctly or you will have undefined behavior.